# Sub-grouping in a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics, lattice, bioconductor

I want to represent data from different individual cells in a xyplot and then give them a color in base of a different category. However, when I have been able to represent this with dots:

```
xyplot( signal ~ time | as.factor(treatment), data=data,groups=cell,
        fill.color = as.character(data$color),
        panel = function(x, y,fill.color,...,subscripts){
          fill = fill.color [subscripts]
          panel.xyplot(x, y,pch=19, col=fill, type ="p")}
)
```

But in this way it is imposible to visually track the cells. Therefore, I want to do the same with lines and polygons as error area but it happens that each time I try, lattice override the second group that should assign the color (or I am not able to tell it properly to lattice. Here is my way to do that:

```
cell<-rep(x = c("A","B","C","D"),50)
signal<-rep(sample(seq(from = 0, to = 50, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE),4)
time<-sort(rep(seq(1,50),4),decreasing = F)
treatment<-rep(c("hard","soft"),50*2)
color<-rep(c("red","orange"),50*2)
data<-data.frame(cell,signal,time,treatment,color)

my.panel2 <- function(x, y, subscripts, col, pch,cex,sd,fill.color,...) {
  low95 <- y-sd[subscripts]
  up95 <- y+sd[subscripts]
  fill=fill.color [subscripts]
  panel.xyplot(x, y, col=fill.color, pch=pch,cex=cex, ...)
  panel.arrows(x, low95, x, up95, angle=90, code=3,lwd=3, 
               length=0.05, alpha=0.2,col=col)
}


xyplot(signal~time|as.factor(treatment), groups=as.factor((data$cell)), 
       data=data, type='l',
       color.line=as.character((data$color)))
```

Thanks;
Santi

Comment: Your code doesn't run. `cell`, `time`, and `treatment` are length 200, `signal` is length 50, and `color` is length 500. The `data.frame(...)` call fails. Also, 5 colors and 4 cell types? What do the colors represent?

Comment: I have already edit the cell ad color vectors so data.frame() doesn't crash. I used 5 colors as example, my real data contains 4 colors and around 100 cells.

Comment: Is there supposed to be one color for each cell type? If not, what do the colors represent??

Comment: In my original dataframe I calculated the vector color in base of hte signal at t=1, may be could be more coherent for the sake of hte example set only  2 color

Comment: If you haven't already, you may want to consider using 'ggplot': http://ggplot2.org/. It makes plotting graphs such as this fairly trivial, one you get data in good format (see http://had.co.nz/reshape/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Vince, he gave me an interesting idea. `ggplot2` is based on layers so I decided to try something similar in lattice with `as.layer()`. First I spitted my data in three groups, one per level

```
fm1<-filter(fmeans, group=="Ave-int")
fm2<-filter(fmeans, group=="Mini-int")
fm3<-filter(fmeans, group=="High-int")
line1<-fm2[43,]
fm3<-rbind(fm3,line1)
```

Then I decided to use a polygon as error band using `panel.polygon()`:

```
my.panel.pol <- function(x, y, subscripts, col,sd,...) {
  plot.line <- trellis.par.get("plot.line")
  xs <- if(is.factor(x)) {
    factor(c(levels(x) , rev(levels(x))), levels=levels(x))
  } else {
    xx <- sort(unique(x))
    c(xx, rev(xx))
  }
  low95 <- y-sd[subscripts]
  up95 <- y+sd[subscripts]
  panel.xyplot(x, y, col=col,...)
  panel.polygon(xs, c(up95, rev(low95)), col=col, alpha=0.2, border=F)
}
```

then represent all data and merge in one graphic

```
   a<-
      xyplot(Mean ~ slice*12 |treatment , fm1,
              layout=c(2,2),col="red",
             grid=T,
             ylim = c(0,max(fmeans$Mean)),
              group = stemcell, type = "l",
             sd=fm1$sd,
             panel.groups= "my.panel.pol",
             panel="panel.superpose")
    b<-xyplot(Mean ~ slice*12 |treatment , fm2,
              layout=c(2,2),col="blue",
              group = stemcell, type = "l",
              sd=fm2$sd,
              panel.groups= "my.panel.pol",
              panel="panel.superpose")
    c<-xyplot(Mean ~ slice*12 |treatment , fm3,
              layout=c(2,2),col="green",
              group = stemcell, type = "l",
              sd=fm3$sd,
              panel.groups= "my.panel.pol",
              panel="panel.superpose")

    a+as.layer(b)+as.layer(c)
```

so here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Please click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows to formally accept your answer. That way when people are browsing questions, they will realize that this question has already been answered.